# SFML Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, macos, sfml

I am following a [tutorial](https://github.com/SFML/cmake-sfml-project) to use SFML. I have also used this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOyp5n2FmZY) to properly download SFML files and move them to their proper file locations. I also used brew to install SFML.

I am currently using an **M2 Mac**, I have downloaded **SFML version 2.5.1_2** and am running the code on **VS Code**.

However, everytime I try to run this code;

```cpp
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    return 0;
}
```

it returns this error:

```cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "sf::String::String(char const*, std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-7676f2.o
  "sf::Window::Window(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-7676f2.o
  "sf::Window::~Window()", referenced from:
      _main in main-7676f2.o
  "sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-7676f2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried scrubbing SFML from my mac twice, however, the error persists. How would I fix this error?

I am sure it is something small and an easy fix, but I am very new to coding and SFML in general. If there is anyway to improve my question please let me know.

Comment: I would guess that SFML downloads are for x64 systems, not arm64. Can you run `readelf -h <sfml_library>` and see what "Machine:" section contains?

Comment: Well, actually looking at it, SFML does not use shared libraries for MacOS but their `.dylib` so `readelf` won't work. Not sure how to check the architecture but there sure is some tool for that.

Comment: This seems like the common issue we see with newbies. Before learning how to program SFML with C++, you should first learn how to program C++ itself. Learning C++ is complicated enough by itself. Your error is not about SFML itself, it's about knowing how to use the tools needed to build C++ programs.